# Display UTF symbol

Tags: javascript, utf-8, reactjs, jsx

I want to display the symbol for Fahrenheit in JSX, in React.

So far I tried this:

```
<h2 className="white-center">{Math.floor(JSON.parse(this.props.item["name"]["temperature"])[month]) + "&#8457"}</h2>
```

And this:

```
<h2 className="white-center">{Math.floor(JSON.parse(this.props.item["name"]["temperature"])[month])} &#8457</h2>
```

However, none worked and `&#8457` is displayed.

How can I display the UTF-8 character?

Comment: have you tried `"\u2109"` or `"℉"` directly ?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a semicolon: `&#8457;`

Comment: Apply palm directly to forehead.  Apply palm directly to forehead.